# Axio's request gets an empty response from Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am working on a small demo application to show how Gatsby, Node.js and MongoDB work together, But I cannot send the data from the Node.js app back to the Gatsby frontend. I use the standard packages like axios, mongodb, mongoose and express. The server gets the `GET` request and  fetches the data from the DB, the console show the 2 fetched documents but they won't get send back to the React component. The web inspector shows this error message: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. I think I do something wrong parsing the data to be send off According to the error. Which is strange since json is the preferred format.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const IndexPage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect( () => {  
    setLoading(true);
    axios.get("http://192.168.178.84:3001/")
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
        setError(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);
   
  if (loading) return "Loading...";
  if (error) return "Error!";

  return (
    <main>
      {loading && data.map((person) => (
        <li key={person._id}> 
          {person.first_name}
        </li>
      ))}
      

    </main>
  )
}
```

Node.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const connectDb = require("./config/mongoConnection");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first_name: String, 
  last_name: String
});
const Persons = mongoose.model('persons', schema); 

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

connectDb();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(`${req.method} ${req.url}`);
  const entries = Persons.find().exec();
  entries.then(res.json(entries));
  entries.then(console.log);
})
mongoose.connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB ");
  app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}`));
});
```

Comment: When you open `http://192.168.178.84:3001` in your browser, does it display the right data?

Comment: This: `loading && data.map((person) =>` should probably be `!loading && data.map((person) => `.  Once it's not loading and there's data you won't render anything.

Comment: Or you don't need the `loading` condition there at all -- you already return if loading is `true`.

Comment: @tromgy ok, deleted the ```loading```. @Jb31 damn no, there are empty curly brackets ```{}``` as I suspected a parser problem?

Answer (score 0):

got it The problem was the Promise object, a minor modification was required. I post the solution:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 // console.log(`${req.method} ${req.url}`);
  const entries = Person.find().exec();
  entries.then((result) => {
    res.json(result);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
});
```

`then()` expects two arguments `(result)` callback and the `catch()` error. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then